# react-native run-android issue on Windows 10

Tags: android, react-native, create-react-native-app

I've developed an app using Create-React-Native-App and usually would test the work using 'npm run android' where Expo client is installed on my device which would load the app once my laptop and mobile is on same WiFi network.

When I used create-react-native-app, the directory structure it laid down looks like this (src directory is created by me):

```
appDirectory\
--.expo\
--node_modules\
--src\
--.bablerc
--.flowconfig
--.gitignore
--.watchmanconfig
--.App.js
--app.json
--App.test.js
--package.json
--README.md
--yarn.lock
```

Now that I am done developing the app, I tried running this command: react-native run-android to install an APK to my device and create environment for both Android and iOS with their respective entry points like index.android.js/index.ios.js but I don't see any of this and all I get as output is:

Scanning folders for symlinks in D:\ROHIT\Projects\appDirectory\node_modules (141ms)

Please help me out with this as I am pretty new to React-Native and unable to understand to generate APK for testing and production, to be installed on various devices for pilot testing

Thanks and best,
Rohit

Comment: find time  to read basic [documentation for react native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) only then you can understand what you are doing and what you have to do.

Comment: @ShahzadMirza I've been reading the documentation since 3 days, I am saying I am just getting that symlink line and nothing after that :)

Comment: check [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13838) on RN or may be your port 8081 is not available thats why packager is not starting check error in your packager npm or yarn.